# File::Copy: Can I use next if failed and also print?

Tags: perl, copy

I am creating a system which, as a part of it's process, should copy many files. I want that if a copy fails, the system will print an error and move to the next iteration (using the Perl `next` statement).

How can I create a one-liner, it if at all?

Currently I have:

```
    copy($source,$dest) or print "-E- Copy failed: $partition fusion SDC wasn't found\n ";
```

I want to add `next` besides the `print`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want everything on one line? `if (!copy($source, $dest)) { ... }` would be much more readable than `copy(...) or (print "..." and next)` or `copy(...) or do { print "..."; next }`

Comment: I don't care splitting it actually. Thank you !

Comment: @Dada, `print "..." and next` will malfunction if there's a print error. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: @ikegami Yup. I deemed that to be an acceptable flow, and provided `do` as a better alternative (which I didn't feel like explaining before getting an answer to my comment; arguably a bit lazy on my part ^^). `,` sounds like a strictly better approach than `&&` though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
EXPR
   or print( ... ), next;
```

```perl
EXPR
   or do {
      print( ... );
      next;
   };
```

```perl
if ( !EXPR ) {
   print( ... );
   next;
}
```

You can remove any/all of the line breaks, but hiding a `next` deep into a line is something I try to avoid.

---

Tip: `warn( ... )` (or `print( STDERR ... )`) should be used in favour of `print( ... )` for error messages.